# Offset one cell down doesn't work for some reason

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have up to 6 records which will be based on the answers located in the row beneath.

My code so far looks like this:

```
 Sub Copy_Data_Correctly(ByRef datSource As Worksheet, datTarget As Worksheet)

 'QUESTION 1

 Const TM_PM As String = "*PM is required*"

 Dim que1 As Range
 Dim ans1 As Range
 Set que1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=TM_PM, _
                                     Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                                     
 If Not que1 Is Nothing Then
 'MsgBox ("The question about PM or TM wasn't found")
 End If

 Set ans1 = que1.Offset(1)

 'QUESTION 2

 Const LID_LIFTED As String = "*be lifted*"

 Dim que2 As Range
 Dim ans2 As Range
 Set que2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100").Find(What:=LID_LIFTED, _
                                     Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
                                     
 If Not que2 Is Nothing Then
 End If

 Set ans2 = que2.Offset(1)

 'EXTRACTING THE DATA
                                   
  Dim lrow1 As Long, lrow2 As Long, lrow3 As Long, lrow4 As Long, lrow5 As Long, lrow6 As Long


  lrow1 = datTarget.Range("E" & datTarget.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  lrow2 = datTarget.Range("F" & datTarget.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


  que1.Copy
     datTarget.Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  ans1.Copy
     datTarget.Range("E" & lrow1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

  que2.Copy
     datTarget.Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  ans2.Copy
     datTarget.Range("F" & lrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

  End Sub
```

If I have the second question & answer standalone, then it works. Unfortunately after adding the Q&A1 the error:

Object variable or with variable not set

occurs at the line:

```
   Set ans1 = que1.Offset(1)
```

why the code behaves like that?

[image]

Comment: Because it's outside the test to see if que1 is Nothing.

Comment: What do you mean outside the test?

Comment: I mean that you test if que1 is nothing but even if it is, your code carries on and tries to use it as a range, which obviously won't work.

Comment: But the same code for que2 works perfectly if I completely remove the wue1 section

Comment: Only if the search value is found. If it isn't, you'll have the same error.

Comment: So do you mean, that I have to place the offset within Is Nothing Then?

Comment: Everything that depends on whether the search values were found should be within the relevant `If...End If` blocks.

Comment: Is `Sheet1` actually `datSource`? Shouldn't `A1:A100` be dynamic (`A1:Alastrow`)? Does it contain values or formulas? If a question is not found, e.g. for column `E`, should the next use the same column `E` or rather `F`? Why do you need the number formats pasted?

Comment: I don't need dynamic, as I am convinced that the data won't exceed row 100th at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Conditionally

- Using the `Find` method, it will attempt to find each string, containing wild characters, from a list in range `A1:A100` of one worksheet (source), then take this matching value (which is different (no wild characters)), and by using `Application.Match`, it will attempt to find a match in the headers of another worksheet (destination). If a match is found, then the result, the value of the cell below the previously found cell, will be written into the first available row. If no match is found, a new header will be created from the value of the found cell, and the value below the found cell will be written into the first available row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData( _
        ByVal wsSource As Worksheet, _
        ByVal wsDestination As Worksheet)
    
    ' Add more: comma separated, no spaces
    Const sCriteriaList As String = "*PM is required,*be lifted*"
    Const sCriteriaListDelimiter As String = ","
    Const sAddress As String = "A1:A100"
    
    Const dfhCellAddress As String = "E1"
    
    Dim sCriteria() As String
    sCriteria = Split(sCriteriaList, sCriteriaListDelimiter)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wsSource.Range(sAddress)
    
    Dim dfhCell As Range: Set dfhCell = wsDestination.Range(dfhCellAddress)
    Dim dfRow As Long: dfRow = dfhCell.Row
    Dim dfCol As Long: dfCol = dfhCell.Column
    Dim dlhCell As Range: Set dlhCell = _
        wsDestination.Cells(dfRow, wsDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    Dim dhrg As Range
    If dlhCell.Column < dfCol Then
        Set dhrg = dfhCell
    Else
        Set dhrg = wsDestination.Range(dfhCell, dlhCell)
    End If
    Dim dlCol As Long: dlCol = dhrg.Columns(dhrg.Columns.Count).Column
    
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = _
        wsDestination.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Dim dRow As Long
    If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
        If dlCell.Row <= dfhCell.Row Then
            dRow = dfhCell.Row + 1
        Else
            dRow = dlCell.Row + 1
        End If
    Else
        dRow = dfhCell.Row + 1
    End If
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sQuestion As String
    Dim sAnswer As String
    
    Dim drrg As Range
    Dim dhIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sCriteria)
        Set sCell = srg.Find( _
            sCriteria(n), srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            sQuestion = sCell.Value
            sAnswer = CStr(sCell.Offset(1).Value)
            dhIndex = Application.Match(sQuestion, dhrg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(dhIndex) Then
                wsDestination.Cells(dRow, dhIndex + dfCol - 1).Value = sAnswer
            Else
                Set dhrg = dhrg.Resize(, dhrg.Columns.Count + 1)
                dlCol = dlCol + 1
                wsDestination.Cells(dfRow, dlCol).Value = sQuestion
                wsDestination.Cells(dRow, dlCol).Value = sAnswer
            End If
        End If
    Next n
    
End Sub
```